# class templates and virtual functions

Tags: c++, templates

Given the code below, why the compiler throws an error (saying that the method `calc()` is not member of `Model2`) when using `Sub<Model2>` instance, if the `fn()` is declared virtual, and works when the `fn()` is not virtual? What is going on?

```
class Model1
{
public:
    void calc(){std::cout<<"Model1 calc"<<std::endl;}
};
class Model2
{
public:
    void calc2(){std::cout<<"Model2 calc"<<std::endl;}
};
template<typename T>
class Super : public T
{
public:
    virtual void fn() // comment virtual for resolution
    { T::calc(); }
};
template<typename T>
class Sub : public Super<T>
{
public:
    void fn()
    { T::calc2(); }
};
int main()
{
    Super<Model1> bes;
    bes.fn();
    Sub<Model2> sts1;
    sts1.fn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can it work if `calc1` and `calc2` are not `static` function members?

Comment: Super inherits from T. One wouldn't write T::calc() in a "normal" class (although it would be ok), this is necesary only in a template class.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for my inattention. Good question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtual methods have to be instantiated in a template, whereas non-virtual methods don't.

Errors depending of `T` "requirement" happen at the moment of instantiation.
Non-virtual methods are instantiated only when used or explicit instantiated.

In your case, when not virtual, `Super<Model2>::fn` is never called (it is `Sub<Model2>::fn`).
In the virtual case, `Super<Model2>::fn` is not called, but has to be instanciated because it is virtual.

Comment: i also wonder about the ops results. can you post a little example please?